# promise with one function argument to then()

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

```
     let promise = new Promise(resolve => {
   setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000);
    });
  promise.then(alert); // shows "done!" after 1 second
```

// in the above snippets ,how alert is taking the value "done" as we are not passing any arguments inside alert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For promise there are two things that can be returned `Accept`(success) `Reject`(failure). Normally we do something like this to achieve the promise response, as you can see here we are taking 2 temporary variables to alert, if success then result variable will be alert and if failed then error variable will be alert.

```js
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => reject(new Error("Whoops!")), 1000);
});

// reject runs the second function in .then
promise.then(
  result => alert(result), // doesn't run
  error => alert(error) // shows "Error: Whoops!" after 1 second
);
```

Incase of you only insterested in succesfully completion then you can use this.

```js
let promise = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000);
});

promise.then(alert); // shows "done!" after 1 second
```

**What it does?** It will actually get result as "done" and as you already have applied alert the "done" will be passed to alert like this `alert("done")`.

To catch directly you can use this:

```js
let promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => reject("failed!"), 1000);
});

promise.catch(alert); // shows "failed!" after 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

as `promise.then` is taking `function with argument "done"` as argument, and `alert` is a `function` it passes the "done" automatically to `alert`

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you passed in the resolve function will be passed down to the callback inside the 'then'.

And alert function takes parameters to show in the alert-box.
So, in short `your promise -> resolve-function -> then -> alert('done')`.

Answer (score 0):

typeof alert is function, so whenever we are sending alert as first parameter of then it is assigned to resolve callback of the Promise.

means resolve("done!") is equal to alert("done!")

below code will not alert as done!

```
let promise = new Promise(resolve => {
setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000);

});
promise.then(alert('not'));
```